# Why where clause is not working while using offset?

Tags: mysql

Well I'm making a web in which i have multiple filters and they are working very fine along the following query

```
SELECT * from userInventory  limit 30 offset 0
```

The above query returns expected number of rows,when i add where clause in it so it becomes

```
SELECT * from userInventory where item_rarity = 'IMMORTAL' limit 30 offset 0
```

So then where clause doesn't works and it returns simple select query result as i used

```
SELECT * from userInventory limit 30 offset 0
```

But i need a query in which where and offset both should works properly,example

```
SELECT * from userInventory where item_name="name" and item_rarity = 'rarity' and usedBy = "usedBy" limit 30 offset 0
```

Note : Without an offset above query is working fine returning the expected result and if increase the offset number result is null

Comment: Please add sample records.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ordernation, like:

```
SELECT * from userInventory where item_name="name" and item_rarity = 'rarity' and usedBy = "usedBy" ORDER BY SOME_FIELD DESC_OR_ASC limit 30 offset 0;
```

Comment: I've tried it and it is working good but when i send a request again with the same offset number unfortunately it ignores the where clause once again and returns as "SELECT * from userInventory limit 30 offset 0"  no where clause

Comment: @MohammadShaheryar so this is not an sql problem, right? Is it php?

Comment: I have no idea what is going wrong,basically I'm making pagination for my web,all of the filters are working fine even though default offset 0 is working fine when i click on page number 1 so obviously offset must be 0 but this time it ignores the where clause i have no idea

Comment: "Ordernation" isn't a word, and the word it most appears to be a misspelling of ("ordination") doesn't apply.